# How much space null double takes in mysql

Tags: mysql

If in mysql table I declare a column with double precision type. And its value is null in a row, would it still take up 8 bytes?

Comment: As always, [the documentation explains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html). Short answer: Being able to be `NULL` does make the field slightly bigger. Actually being `NULL` does not make it smaller. Unless your column is *variable length* like `VARCHAR`, it does not ever vary in length.

Comment: How many `DOUBLE` values are you storing that you actually care about size? If it's a lot, remember, fixed-length rows are faster to process because computing access offsets in the table is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming InnoDB, the default storage engine for MySQL.

In the COMPACT row format and more recent row formats, a NULL is not stored in the data portion of a record.

> Each index record contains a 5-byte header that may be preceded by a variable-length header. The header is used to link together consecutive records, and for row-level locking.

> The variable-length part of the record header contains a bit vector for indicating NULL columns. If the number of columns in the index that can be NULL is N, the bit vector occupies CEILING(N/8) bytes. (For example, if there are anywhere from 9 to 16 columns that can be NULL, the bit vector uses two bytes.) **Columns that are NULL do not occupy space other than the bit in this vector.**

Only in the obsolete REDUNDANT row format do columns occupy space when they are NULL. But I assume you're not using this row format (unless you chose to do so deliberately).

Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html